# C program-linked list-syntax

Tags: c, syntax, linked-list

This a function for adding a node in a linked list.

```
void addNode(struct Node *head, int n) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = n;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    Node *cur = head;
    while(cur) {
        if(cur->next == NULL) {
            cur->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what the while condition is here for? I know that after adding a node the previous node's address should be changed from NULL to whatever the next node's address is. But what's confusing me is how the while condition would work. I mean what does 'while (cur)' means here…isn't there supposed to be a condition inside the brackets?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework answering website.

Comment: This code in not C. Either retag your question to proper language or provide valid C example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. In C use [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and its friends to allocate data chunks of memory dynamically. The common idiom is like:

```
Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
```

Don' forget to deallocate it when not needed by [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) standard function. Moreover you should also always check returned value from `malloc()`, determining if it succeded.

Now back to your question:

```
while (cur) {
    // ...
}
```

`cur` is evaluated as expression, that you can think of true and false (more precisely `0` is treatead as false and every other value, excepting these obtaintable from cast to another type e.g. `0.0` (`double`) are treated as true). It's actually more descriptive (and probably more intuitive for you at the first look) to write this specific loop's condition as:

```
while (cur != NULL) {
    // ...
}
```

These both forms are semantically the same in your context.

---

Note that `while` loop might be not entered at all when `cur` (i.e. `head` parameter) is null pointer.

Comment: And you might also note that the code doesn't work properly on an empty list because there isn't a way to update the head in the calling code.